# Assigning class constructor arguments private variables in coffeescript

Tags: constructor, coffeescript, private

I've found that I can use private variables in coffeescript classes like so:

```
class Book
    title = null
    numberOfPages = null

    constructor: (t, nop) ->
        title = t
        numberOfPages = nop

    ripOutPages: (numPages) -> numberOfPages = numberOfPages - numPages

    isEmpty: -> numberOfPages == 0
```

So my first question is, is this considered a reasonable approach in coffeescript?

And my second question is, is there a neater way to achieve this (i.e. not having to initialise the variables in the class body then assign them in the constructor)?

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the generated JS code, you will notice that those are more like "private" *static* class properties, not "private" instance properties:

```
var Book;

Book = (function() {
  var numberOfPages, title;

  title = null;

  numberOfPages = null;

  function Book(t, nop) {
    title = t;
    numberOfPages = nop;
  }

  Book.prototype.ripOutPages = function(numPages) {
    return numberOfPages = numberOfPages - numPages;
  };

  Book.prototype.isEmpty = function() {
    return numberOfPages === 0;
  };

  return Book;

})();
```

Every instance you create shares the same `title` and `numberOfPages` variables. So I guess the answer is: No, it's not a suitable approach for what you are trying to do.

JavaScript simply doesn't have "private" properties (yet).

Comment: Oh dear, I should have checked the generated JS, that's not what I wanted at all. Thanks for your reply, very helpful although not what I wanted to hear.

Answer (score 0):

If you really-really want "private" variable, you might want to define your methods as closures:

```
class Book
    constructor: (t, nop) ->
        # Those are two local variables:
        title = t
        numberOfPages = nop

        # The following closures will have access to the two variable above:
        @title = -> title                     # <- accessor to title
        @numberOfPages = -> numberOfPages     # <- accessor to numberoOfPage
        @ripOutPages = (numPages) -> numberOfPages = numberOfPages - numPages

    isEmpty: -> @numberOfPages() == 0
    # ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    # declared "as usual" as it uses accessor to access the "private" variables


# Some tests
lotr = new Book("The Lord of the Rings",1137)
hobbit = new Book("The Hobbit",276)

console.log lotr.title(), lotr.numberOfPages()
console.log hobbit.title(), hobbit.numberOfPages()

lotr.ripOutPages 100
console.log lotr.title(), lotr.numberOfPages()
```

Producing:

```
The Lord of the Rings 1137
The Hobbit 276
The Lord of the Rings 1037
```

Comment: I don't want the private members to be accessible outside at all, I just want them accessible from all methods.